# Add rigid body physics for an object with a modifier and keyframe

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

It is possible in blender to add rigid body physics for objects that have modifiers and are keyframed?
[image]

[image]

Now the left object doesn't interact with the right object...
Even if I check "Animated" in the rigid body settings

Comment: modifiers: yes, keyframes: no -> you have to decide, whether you want the animation be done by rigid body or by keyframes. You can change the two settings with the checkbox "animated" in the rigid body settings